# Production level Exception handling in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, exception

I have a scenario :

```
            UI<--->Spring boot micro-service REST API<--->server
```

Now, there is a situation in which I want to handle custom exceptions(which I am aware how to do) in order to return specific Http Status and message back to UI when server responds in certain manner for e.g. 500 should return "Please return after a while" insteal of "internal server error". The maven project for our micro-service is divided into 3 layers (sub maven projects) i.e. Business, Web and Domain. Where web contains controller class, Business contains Service class and Domain contains @Entity, @Components etc.

I want to know in order to handle the above mentioned exception let say HTTP Status 500, should be done at business layer? or at web layer i.e. controller level. What would be the best possible solution? (I am aware of ResponseEntity and how it can provide a customized response to UI).

I personally believe that if I include custom exception class at Business Level and return that in Controller class using response entity after checking the response status would do the trick. But officials feel that it should be done at service level? I am not able to understand why(it makes the process more complex)? can anyone suggest which solution is best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officials are right, it should be in Service Layer. I would say best practice would be to use @ExceptionHandler. As the downside to handling the exception in the controller method is that it makes the code less readable and might be repeated across many controller methods.

I would recommend having a base class for your controllers with the @ExceptionHandler defined. This way it can be used for many different controllers, without any code duplication. This would be more readable than the exception resolver approach, but could be used in conjunction
This is clearly explained [here](https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling)

Comment: Thanks!! This blog helps me understand the logic behind not handling the exception at controller level.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle error in a global level, you can use @ControllerAdvice which is very easy when comes to the handling custom exceptions as well as runtime exceptions.

you can throw exceptions from business layer to web controllers and define a @ControllerAdvice class to catch those errors and provide responses with correct response status.

For Ex:-

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { IllegalArgumentException.class, IllegalStateException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        String bodyOfResponse = "This should be application specific";
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse, 
          new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }
}
```

and throw those Exception classes from the controller classes also, you dont need to catch exception from the controllers.

Hope this helps to you...

Above code snipplet i took from [here](http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Error response is usually generated by `@ExceptionHandler` matching your exception type and maybe registered with `@ConrtrollerAdvice` as described [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).

API should be standardised (e.g. http://jsonapi.org/) and designed primarily for developers. Returning "Please return after a while" instead of "Internal Server Error" makes little sense to me. It's a 500 HTTP status response of uncertain reason e.g. `NullPointerException` somewhere deep in the code.